how to use s3api to find N largest files of specific StorageClass
This query returns the 5 largest items, but ignores the StorageClass
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket spinhead --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==STANDARD] && sort_by(Contents, &Size)[-5:]'
Items returned are all StorageClass STANDARD_IA
Assumed the query would return only items with StorageClass = STANDARD
I'm struggling to find any clear documentation on how to compose queries for this tool. Queries I copy/paste from online all seem to work fine, but the moment I modify a single aspect, they blow up.
Ultimate goal here is to find very large files using STANDARD StorageClass which I can move to STANDARD_IA
EDIT
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket spinhead --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==STANDARD] | sort_by(Contents, &Size)[-5:]'
returns
In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"
and
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket spinhead --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==STANDARD] | sort_by(@, &Size)[-5:]'
returns
[]

Is this an S3 compatible service?

With the && operator, you're asking if one list or the other list is present, not sorting the first list, you'd want to use the | operator to do that with something like --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==\STANDARD`] | sort_by(@, &Size)[-5:]'`

@pierpy Yes, it's connected to the aws cli which I use for S3

This works as expected:
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket spinhead --query "Contents[?StorageClass == 'STANDARD'] | sort_by(@, &Size)[-3:]"

Where would I learn what the &&, |, and @ operators do with this query? Or how to compose these queries in general? I understand that it's all based on JMESPath, but going down that rabbit hole seems excessive just to understand S3 queries.
The documentation is sparse at best. I've found virtually all the useful info I currently have using Google and reading Qs and As here.

Yes, they're JMESPath queries, so if you want to learn them, maybe start with a tutorial on them.

Those appear helpful. Thank you.
